# Grep lines in file1 if not found in file2

Tags: awk

I tried this, which I though should work, but it does not 
`grep -vhFxf`

*file1*

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

*file2*

```
aaaa
cccc
dddd
```

---

output

```
bbbb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `comm` command,

```
$ comm -23 file1 file2
bbbb
```

It's better to sort the files before fedding it to the `comm` command,

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: I think OP meant a different thing. grep a pattern in file 2 , if it is not found, grep in file1

Comment: no, he wants to print the lines which are in file 1 and it isn't exists in the file2.

Comment: Right avinash. comm maybe works if I sort the files

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for showing the comm function